# Можно ли в Destroy() указать какой именно объект удалить?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, как указать Destroy какой именно объект удалить? Например: У меня есть три объекта, при коллизии с первым необходимо удалить третий, при столкновении с третьем, нужно удалить второй.
Спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам требуется. В Destroy передается конкретный объект который и удаляется. Вам нужно написать некий контроллер который будет описывать логику поведения в случае столкновения. Ловите столкновение на объектах и в контроллере обрабатываете.

Answer (score 1):

к примеру возьмем метод `OnTriggerEnter`, у него есть входной параметр `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` далее вы можете уже работать с переменной other и проверять на какой обьект сработал триггер.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.CompareTag("Player")){
        Тут код который срабатывает при условии что в триггер попал обьект с тегом Player
    }
}
```

Постарался описать вам в примитивном примере логику работы. Вам же придется вероятно получать тег обьекта и уже в условиях определять, что произойдет если обьект-1, обьект-2 и тд.

Answer (score 1):

Destroy(Объект для уничтожения, (перегрузка) срок времени жизни (через сколько секунд объект будет уничтожен));

Попробуйте использовать:
Advanced C# Messenger
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Advanced_CSharp_Messenger

Или же укажите в массиве объекты которые вы хотели бы использовать.